# I am trying to redirect if an image does not exist on my site

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site where if a user goes to `www.example.com/string` and if that `string.jpg` exists in `www.example.com/images/profile/` then I would like it to redirect to `www.example.com/index.php?u=string` but if the image does not exist I want it to redirect to `www.example.com`.

I have tried using the following in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But that redirects evrything even if the image does not exits

Answer (score 0):

So, if user request page A, and file B exists, goto C?

I don't think the apache developers have thought it usefull to redirect only if some exists. At least I can not see the purpose.

But if everything redirects to index.php, then put the code to check for the existance of the file there, and let index.php redirect again to the frontpage if not.

But also, isn't index.php the default page anyway?

Comment: This is not true. ModRewrite fully supports conditional routing based on file / directory existence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the file exists using RewriteCond. If so, then redirect to that image, otherwise pass the request to index.php

```
# Make sure it's not a direct URL to a file or a directory.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Check if the request URI exists in the images folder.
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/profile%{REQUEST_URI}.jpg -f

# If the image exists, redirect to that.
RewriteRule ^ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/images/profile{%REQUEST_URI}.jpg [L]

# By default, pass the request string to our application.
RewriteRule ^ index.php?u=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I get a 500 Internal Server Error when i use this.

Comment: I was missing a space between the first RewriteRule. Can you try it again? Also, check the output of your error log. Usually it's in /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: [28-Jun-2016 14:37:13 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  include_once(http://example.org/analyticstracking.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in /home3/alextpoma/public_html/example.org/index.php on line 152

Comment: That's a problem in your index.php file, not the RewriteCode. You have an error on line 152 of index.php

Comment: Well it's still routing to your index.php, so I imagine something has changed in the request. To debug further, we'd have to see what exactly is going on around line 152 and the behavior of the HTTP request. If you would feel more comfortable with a strict PHP approach, then you can use the method described by the other answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Give me one second to update the rules and conditions.

Comment: Thank you for all this help its being driving me crazy all day

Comment: I've updated it with the new rules. However, keep in mind that your approach is a little flawed. If you are placing this in the root of example.com, then it will cause an infinite loop whenever a request does not have an image. (It will load www.example.com over and over). What do you want the default behavior to do? That is, when the image is not there.

Comment: Basically, I have a site where want to let users visit www.example.com/string and whatever string they input will be used on www.example.com/index.php?u=string if I have an image for that string then that image will be loaded if the image (string) does not exist then it will use a random image but that string will populate the text.

Comment: So then by default, all requests should do index.php?u=string. There is no secondary redirect. Just check first if the image exists, if so, redirect to that.

Comment: I've updated the rules & conditions to match that behavior. Please keep in mind that the query parameter U will have a leading slash. You can remove this using `rtrim`.

Comment: I have php code to handle the if no image exists but i dont want my users to manually type www.example.com/index.php?u=string and just type www.example.com/string

Would it be possible to do www.example.com/u/string ?

Comment: If you checking for the file existence in `index.php` then why bother with a redirect at all? Just route all requests to `index.php`

Comment: I routed them all to using
'RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,L,QSA]'
but the problem was the images were being redirected too so no images were being displayed

Comment: As in hardcoded URls to images? Like /images/a.jpg? You can avoid that using the two conditions I used in the above answer.

Comment: You can tweak the conditions I gave you to suit your needs. The comments are pretty self explanatory. If you have questions regarding what each statement does, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if file_exists('filename'), an existing PHP function.

Then you can redirect using PHP headers accordingly.

This will completely avoid the RewriteRule, and you can add the appropriate PHP headers.

In order to make this work, you'll need to detect *file*.jpg in the URL, send the request to a PHP file (that checks if file exists), then finally redirect with the PHP redirect header you would like to use.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just do that in php? Your rewrite rule redirects everything, so leave that in tact. Now just have the following code in your index.php:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['u']) && !file_exists('./images/profile/'.basename($_GET['u'])) ) {
    header('Location: http://www.example.com');
    exit(0);
}

//Do all your other wonderful stuff here.. for instance:
if( isset($_GET['u']) && file_exists('./images/profile/'.basename($_GET['u'])) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    readfile('./images/profile/'.basename($_GET['u']));
    exit(0);
} else {
    echo("Hello world!");
}
```

Obviously be careful not to create an infinite circular redirection (e.g. if index.php is your default page, the redirecting people to the default page will put them in an endless circle of getting redirected to the same page).

Comment: Your code results in an infinite redirect-loop. The query parameter 'u' will not be set upon your first redirect, and that clause will run over and over.

Comment: I warned against the fact that unless the default page at http://www.example.com is **not** index.php it would result in a redirect loop. But if this is the case, then it is _exactly_ the behaviour that would result from what the original question said they want the behaviour to be.
E: I've modified the logic to avoid that behaviour, but it is not exactly what the question asked.